# Error al consumir web service C# en VB6 o aplicación asp clásico

Tags: c#, webservice, asp, vb6, dll

tengo una aplicación en asp clásico la cual debe consumir un web service.
Para esto tengo el siguiente esquema:

Web Service SOAP --> DLL (Libreria de clases) C# --> DLL (Visual Basic 6) --> Aplicación Asp Clásico

He referenciado el servicio en el proyecto C# y lo compilo para generar el .dll y el .dll.config, los posiciono en una carpeta en el disco local C: y registro mediante CMD el archivo (MiServicioProxy).dll copiando el .dll y .dll.config en SysWOW64 y System32.

La registro con el siguiente comando:

```
copy "C:\components\MiServicioProxy.dll" "C:\Windows\System32"
pause
copy "C:\components\MiServicioProxy.dll" "C:\Windows\SysWOW64"
pause
copy "C:\mtscomponents\MiServicioProxy.dll.config" "C:\Windows\SysWOW64"
pause
copy "C:\mtscomponents\MiServicioProxy.dll.config" "C:\Windows\System32"
pause


C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe MiServicioProxy.dll /codebase /tlb:MiServicioProxy.tlb
pause
```

Una vez registrado me genera un .tlb el cual lo uso para referenciarlo en el proyecto de VB6, genero la dll con la referencia del tlb; y registro el (MiServicioVB6).dll en el Servicio de Componentes.

Al ejecutar la aplicación montada en el IIS (versión 10) con un asp de prueba me manda el siguiente error:

*#error -2146233079 No se encontró el elemento de extremo predeterminado que hace referencia al contrato 'WebServiceReference.Service' en la sección de configuración de cliente de ServiceModel. La razón puede ser que no se encontró ningún archivo de configuración para la aplicación o que no se encontró ningún elemento de extremo correspondiente a este contrato en el elemento de cliente*

El código que utilizo de prueba es el siguiente:

```
dim objServicio
set objServicio = server.CreateObject("MiServicioVB6.MiServicioClase")
result = objServicio.GetEvaluacoin("0090", "1")
response.write(result)
response.end
```

¿Que es lo que me falta hacer?

Comment: Por favor podrias completar tu pregunta indicando. 1) Que version del IIS (es decir en que sistema operativo), ... ademas seria util si colocas como registrate la DLL? si bien dices que copiaste en ambas carpetas? (SysWOW64 y System32.) cuales comando ejecutaste para el registro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final pude resolverlo con una alternativa sencilla que a mi parecer podría ayudar a muchos.

Mi problema radicó en la lectura del .dll.config, por alguna razón no lograba dar con el al ejecutar la dll, por ello la solución final fue la siguiente:

Dentro de mi código, agregué las cadenas del app.config a mi código en cada uno de los métodos que utiliza el Web service.

```
        public int metodoLlamaAWebService(int parametro){ 
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding((BasicHttpSecurityMode)SecurityMode.None);
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 700000;
        EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress("url");
        OUGWServiceClient ObjWebService = new OUGWServiceClient(binding, epa);
        }
```

Creé la instancia para llamar al tipo de binding, configuré el tamaño máximo de la respuesta y finalmente el endpoint address con la url del web service.
Esto para añadirlo al objeto del web service cuando se realice un request.

Así resultó, integrar las cadenas de conexión al WS en el mismo código.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder utilizar un componente (libreria .NET) en ASP Clasico y/o VB6 tienes que exponer esa libreria (o la clases quieres referenciar).

Si bien tienes la opcion o checkbox en Visual Studio para que la libreria que estamos desarrollando sea "Visible en COM", e incluso para registrarla en el momento de crear el release en la maquina donde estamos desarrollando. Me parece mejor realizarlo "manualmente" es decir... estos pasos

1. Referenciar el nuget nuget component [System.Runtime.InteropServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.InteropServices/)
2. Agregar los atributos e las clases que queremos "referenciar" o utilizar
   [Guid](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute?view=net-5.0), [ComVisible](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute?view=net-5.0), [ProgId](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.progidattribute?view=net-5.0). Mas info [Interoperating with unmanaged code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/)
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Compilar en modo release y colocarlo en la ubicacion que vamos registrar (ya que alli quedara en el servidor)
4. Registrar nuestro componente con la herramienta [Regasm.exe (Assembly Registration Tool)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool)

- En sistemas operativos 64bits

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

- En Sistemas operativos 32bits

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

- Ejemplo de un registro

```
.\RegAsm.exe "D:\dev\dll-com-visible\StarwarsCharacters.NET48.dll" /codebase
```

IMPORTANTE! Aqui si estas en el IIS deberias ver como esta configurado el Application Pool si habilitado o no que sea a 32bits dependiendo de eso tomara el componente registrado para Framework64 o no.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Arme un ejemplo (tipo tutorial)

- [Consume a NET library from ASP Classic (or VB6 via Visible COM)](https://github.com/fernandezja/consume-net-library-from-asp-classic)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Comment: Gracias por responder, de hecho tengo esa misma configuración manual, lo que hace diferente el proyecto de ejemplo que me muestras y el que tengo, es que en mi caso está consumiendo el web service (SOAP), al tener el .tlb generado a partir del registro, y referenciado en VB6 para generar la dll puente, no encuentra su archivo de configuración.